# Grub_rescue . Grub file not found

Tags: grub, rescue

file normal.mod not found appearing on grub rescue screen. No other files except lost+found appearing on (hd0,msdos7).My system is not booting after I long pressed shutdown button when screen got struck . I installed ubuntu long back after windows 10 through unetbootin without cd/pendrive .

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu from USB drive.

Comment: Thankyou ! I reinstalled os .Now it's working fine